# How can I show actual model names when using ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

When using ember-data and ember-cli, model instances are reported in the console and browser extension (via `toString()` with something like `<(subclass of DS.Model):ember815:1234>`. How can have the actual model name be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolver is aware of naming can be extended to attach properties to classes as they are resolved. Then the `toString()` method can be overridden on `DS.Model`.

In ext/resolve-model-names.coffee

```
`import Resolver from 'ember/resolver'`

Resolver.reopen({
  resolve: function (fullName) {
    var parsedName = this.parseName(fullName);
    var resolved = this._super(fullName);
    if (resolved && parsedName.type === 'model') {
      resolved.typeKey = parsedName.name.camelize();
    }
    return resolved;
});

DS.Model.reopen({
  toString: function() {
    "(DS.Model) " + this.constructor.typeKey + " #" + this.get('id');
  }
});
```

In app.js

```
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import './ext/resolve-model-names';

var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  // ...
  Resolver: Resolver
})
```

Now you will see `(DS.Model)Post#1234`

Actually my code is organized a bit differently, hopefully this is clear enough.

Comment: @rwjblue reports that setting `EmberENV.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS` (commented out in app.js as of ember-cli v0.0.37) will fix this automatically.

Comment: What's the best way to do this now?

Comment: Updated to what I'm using for v1.8

Comment: @aceofspades how are you getting a handle on the correct resolver? I can't get it right https://gist.github.com/dadamssg/a0ccbf8d84604c4e6207

Comment: In your app.js, you'll want to import the file where you override the resolver, then assign it to your application. I've added some details above.